# Letters in memory timings

Tags: memory

Why do some RAM modules have letters in their memory timings and what do those letters represent?
I have a 2GB 2Rx8 PC3-10600R who's memory timings are written as 09-11-B1-P2 on the ram module itself

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the source where you saw those timings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know *exactly* what those numbers represent, but they are not timings, they are die, manufacturing, JEDEC descriptors etc.

page 12 ( http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global/file/product/ddr3_product_guide_dec_12-0.pdf )

> 5.1  RCD Identification in JEDEC Description in Module Label
>
> 5.2  Label Example 4GB 2Rx8 PC3 - 12800R - 11 - 11 - B1 - P2

The "P2" is in a table in the "JEDEC Description" column. The "B1" appears to be a die configuration, but again, I am not that familiar with the information presented.